# Handlebars helper returns [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to return html tag instead of string using below handlebars helper code.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getFeatureValue', function(v1,v2, options) {
    var features = v2[v1];
    if(features == true){
        return $.parseHTML('<span class="tick"></span>');
    }
```

but i am getting [object HTMLSpanElement] as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return html in an Handlebars helper you have to return a `Handlebars.SafeString` object, like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getFeatureValue', function(v1,v2, options) {
    var features = v2[v1];
    if(features == true){
         return new Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="tick"></span>');
    }
});
```

I believe another option is use triple brackets when you call the helper like this: `{{{getFeatureValue}}}`. But i'm not sure, so correct me if i'm wrong.